# get out of while loop if I see back to back same character

Tags: c

I'm suppose to read lines of input similar to this

```
1234-56789   11:22:33:44: .... :88
```

where the right side can be at most 8 double digit integers. If there is a shortage of integers, it will be in the following format

```
1234-56789   11:22:33::
```

The last digit will always be followed by two colons. I've tried the following

```
while((Line + tot) != ':' && (Line + tot + 1) != ':')
while(Line + tot && (Line + tot + 1) != ':')
while(sscanf(Line + tot, "%c%c", &firstColon, &secondColon) != 2)
```

Will all three lines above I continue to go inside the while loop after scanning two colons together, which I don't want because I know I don't have any more integers to follow. With the third while loop I'm 100% sure I assign the colons to their respective places because I printed their values out but I'm still unsure why it keeps going in... I'm using tot as my arrayIndex so that I don't read from the beginning every time. Thank in advance for your time.

Comment: i'm not sure why I'm being downvoted..please comment so that I can fix my error

Comment: That's a reasonable request.  First, your code will be much easier to read if you indent it properly (especially if it involves nested loops).  Second, please provide a minimal example that compiles and exhibits the error.  Third, please state clearly what the error is and what the program should be doing.

Comment: Those are colons, not semicolons. This is a colon: `:`. This is a semicolon: `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while((Line + tot) != ':' && (Line + tot + 1) != ':')
while(Line + tot && (Line + tot + 1) != ':')
```

These are wrong because `Line + tot` is a pointer and won't be `':'`.
Moreover, `a != ':' && b != ':'` become false in `a = '1', b = ':'`.
This means that this is not a good expression to check if there are two semicolons.

`while(sscanf(Line + tot, "%c%c", &firstSemi, &secondSemi) != 2)`

This is wrong because this only checks if there are only zero or one character.

Try this:

```
while(*(Line + tot) != ':' || *(Line + tot + 1) != ':')
while(sscanf(Line + tot, "%c%c", &firstSemi, &secondSemi) != 2 || firstSemi != ':' || secondSemi != ':')
```

Note that `firstSemi` and `secondSemi` must be type `char` to use in this way.

Comment: I hope I didn't mean to imply that I was trying to use all 3 to get out of my while loop. I tried each one separately. However, the first while loop in my post works now, logic the same.  I wasn't retrieving the value from the pointer with *, thanks a lot!